# Align two divs horizontally side by side center to the page using bootstrap css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please refer below code what i tried

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="center-block">First Div</div>
  <div class="center-block">Second DIV </div>
</div>
```

output :

```
First Div
SecondDiv
```

Expected output :

```
                      First Div        Second Div
```

i want to align the two divs horizontally  center to page using bootstrap css. how can i do this ? i dont want to use simple css and floating concept to do this. because i need to make use of the bootstrap css to work in all kind of layouts (i.e. all window size and resolutions ) instead of using media query.

Answer (score 234, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            ONE
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            TWO
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Have a read of the grid system section of the Bootstrap docs to familiarise yourself with how Bootstrap's grids work:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Thanks. can i know what is col-xs-6 ? id div count increased means how to modify this

Comment: col-xs-6 allocates half of the available 12 column grid. If you read the Bootstrap docs I linked to in my answer it should all make sense after some trial and error on your part :-)

Comment: whether it will works when window resized or screen resolution changed ?

Comment: Yes, it will work. Leaving it just with those classes attached will work on all screen sizes.

Comment: Why `xs` and not `md` ?

Comment: @Alexander - using xs means the two divs will be side-by-side at all screen sizes from mobile up to desktop.

Comment: Okay, so xs is for all solutions and e.g. lg is only for higher solutions?

Comment: @Alexander - Yeah, if you use only xs it will be used for all higher devices sizes. Usual practice is to specify xs for small devices devices then maybe an md class which will be used by medium devices and upwards.

Comment: Nice intro to responsive design in these comments :)

Comment: For bootstrap 4 that should be `col-6` (the `xs` infix was removed) https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#global-changes

Answer (score 39):

Use the bootstrap classes `col-xx-#` and `col-xx-offset-#`

So what is happening here is your screen is getting divided into 12 columns. In `col-xx-#`, `#` is the number of columns you cover and offset is the number of columns you leave.

For `xx`, in a general website, `md` is preferred and if you want your layout to look the same in a mobile device, `xs` is preferred.

With what I can make of your requirement,

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">First Div</div>
  <div class="col-md-8">Second DIV </div>
</div>
```

Should do the trick.

Answer (score 17):

Alternate Bootstrap 4 solution (this way you can use divs which are smaller than *col-6*):

[image: Horizontal Align Center]

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-4">
      One of two columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      One of two columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[More](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment)

Answer (score 5):

To align two divs horizontally you just have to combine two classes of Bootstrap:
Here's how:

```
<div class ="container-fluid">
  <div class ="row">
    <div class ="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        First Div
    </div>
    <div class ="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        Second Div
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
          First Div
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
          Second Div
       </div>
   </div>
```

This does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative which I did programming Angular:

```
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-7">
             Left
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-5">
             Right
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Anyone going for Bootstrap 5 (beta as on date), here is what worked for me. In my case, I had to align two items in the card's header section side-by-side:

```
<div class="card small-card text-white bg-secondary">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between card-header">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <h4>100+ Components</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="ml-auto">
        <!--<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 ml-auto"> -->
            <i class="data-feather hoverzoom" data-feather="grid"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, adipscing elitr, sed diam
            nonumy eirmod tempor ividunt labor dolore magna.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The catch here is `justify-content-between` and `ml-auto`. You can get more info [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/#align-items) at the official link. And a live working example [here](https://github.com/ajkr195/Avni/blob/main/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Alternative for bootstrap 5

````
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      Column
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      Column
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      Column
    </div>
  </div>
</div>```
````

Answer (score 0):

The response provided by Ranveer (second answer above) absolutely does NOT work.

He says to use `col-xx-offset-#`, but that is not how offsets are used.

If you wasted your time trying to use `col-xx-offset-#`, as I did based on his answer, the solution is to use `offset-xx-#`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend css grid over bootstrap if what you really want, is to have more structured data, e.g. a side by side table with multiple rows, because you don't have to add class name for every child:

```
// css-grid: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_grid
// https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto; // 20vw 40vw for me because I have dt and dd
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.grid-container > div {
  padding: 20px;
}


<div class="grid-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```

[css-grid](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-erwo1k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
Make sure you wrap your "row" inside the class "container" . Also add reference to bootstrap in your html.
Something like this should work:
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
 <body>
     <p>lets learn!</p>
  <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: red;">
                  ONE
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-2" style="background-color: blue;">
                  TWO
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-4" style="background-color: green;">
              THREE
           </div>
          </div>
      </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 4+, `col-xs-6` doesn't exist. Instead use `col-6`:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            ONE
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            TWO
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```