# What is the best way put two div side by side with bootstrap 4

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I read a post on stackoverflow about the way to put two div side by side. They suggest two different techniques and I wanted to know the best way to do it. You can read the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150006/align-two-divs-horizontally-side-by-side-center-to-the-page-using-bootstrap-css). I tried to find by myself if there was another solution because they looked a little bit a weird to me. I found a third solution.

Do someone have any ideas about the best way to put two div side by side ?

Here are the three solutions that I found.

Solution 1

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            ONE
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            TWO
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Solution 2

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
 <td class="active">Place image here</td>
 <td class="success">Place text here</td>
</table>
```

Solution 3

```
<div class="d-inline-block">one</div>
<div class="d-inline-block">two</div>
```

EDIT : 
I maybe need to explain a little bit more my question. I would like to do a bootstrap card with a title on the left side of the header, and some action buttons in the right side. Using the third solution, I end up with something like this.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h3 class="card-title d-inline-block">title</h3>
    <div class="float-right d-inline-block">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">action</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <span>body</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it a good way to do this kind of things, or is there a better way ? For example the first solution, that a lot of people says that is the best one.

I'm learning bootstrap and I really want to know more about the best practices. Thus, I'm also interested in understanding for each solution, in what kind of context it's preferable to use one instead another.

Thanks for sharing your knowledge and for the time you allowed to this question.

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I edit my post to be more precise, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you use the first solution, as it is the way the Bootstrap grid is intended to be used.

You can find more information about it [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/)

Under the "How it works" section you have a set of rules/guidelines that you can refer to when using the Bootstrap grid, so that you get each tag/classname in the right order.

Further down the page you will find a lot of other useful information and examples on how to use the Bootstrap grid, and how utilize it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure best practice would be solution 1 as that is one of the bootstrap examples..

It also works well for responsive design.