# Components next to each other

Tags: css, angular

I have a doubt about using Angular. I need to place the sentences next to each other. These are two different components that I created. I want recipe-list works and recipes-details works and these two sentences should show next to each other

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5 ">
    <app-recipe-list></app-recipe-list>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <app-recipes-details></app-recipes-details>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<p>recipe-list works!</p> <p>recipes-details works!</p>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Align two divs horizontally side by side center to the page using bootstrap css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150006/align-two-divs-horizontally-side-by-side-center-to-the-page-using-bootstrap-css)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that component here take full width of window. So first, apply class to component directly:

```html
<div class="row">
  <app-recipe-list class="col-5"></app-recipe-list>
  <app-recipes-details class="col-7"></app-recipes-details>
</div>
```

But also give them style `display: inline-block;`. The best way would be to apply `:host` pseudoclass in component's css (recipe-list.component.css and recipes-details.component.css):

```
:host {
  display: inline-block;
}
```